# Chinese CH340 Arduino Uno - Burning stand allone chip

Tags: ftdi, firmware

I followed regular tutorial and I was able to burn boot-loader on my standalone ATM328 chip, but because I'm using this [CH340 UNO](http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ALCYIFXXXXa_XXXXq6xXFXXXj/Hot-sales-NEW-UNO-R3-ATmega328P-CH340-Mini-USB-Board-for-Compatible-Arduino-free-shipping.jpg) and example is with regular UNO, I can't just remove the chip from there (CH340 UNO) and upload the code directly to my new standalone chip trough that board.

So what I tried was to use my [FTDI](http://www.canadarobotix.com/serial-ttl/ftdi-cable-5v-vcc-3-3v-i-o) cable, so I hooked up GND, RX, TX and VCC for my breadboard from there, but when I tried to upload a sketch I keep getting that message that programmer is not responding.

So I was wondering, is there a way to use this Chinese board to upload sketch to my new chip without de-soldering the chip from that board as option one.

As option two what I'm doing wrong with FTDI cable and why I'm not able to upload sketch directly like that? I saw some comments related to some auto-reset that needs to be implemented but I'm not following that part, not sure what I need to hookup extra for that...

UPDATE

Here's how my board look like:
[image]

**Update 2:**

**OK, everything works great now! I just needed one pull-up resistor for reset pin.**

Thanks everyone!

Comment: you also need to physically connect Reset (RST/DTR)

Comment: What is DTR I don't see that pin on my FTDI cable. So that is RTS pin from here ? 
http://www.canadarobotix.com/serial-ttl/ftdi-cable-5v-vcc-3-3v-i-o

Comment: some FTDI breakouts/cables use RTS, others use DTR. Both ~kinda~ do the same thing: reset your MCU before uploading the sketch. (So the bootloader will know to expect something from the serial port). Note that some breakouts will need a 100nF cap in series with this connection, others wont.

Comment: Same thing, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: How do you connect DTR or RTS?  Did you follow the *full* guide with pullup resistor and series capacitor?  When you switch from one serial device to another, you probably have to point the IDE at the new port, did you do that??  In theory you could use your CH340 board if you hold its onboard ATmega in reset.

Comment: I tried both scenarios but keep getting the same error. I put 100nF in series with RTS and Reset but nothing is changed. I don't have any resistor for reset... Do I need any? And yes I pointed in IDE to new port...and I also tried with all of these programmers.

Comment: I have updated my original question with my board image, please take a look.

Comment: What should be the value for that pull-up resistor?

Comment: Try [Arduino ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) to flash standalone chip. Try to flash bootloader first as you didin't mention anything about it and bare chips are just empty.

Comment: I was able to successfully burn bootloader, I just had an issue with uploading sketch later, but that was my fault. I put pull-up resistor on wrong pin :) Everything is ok now.

Comment: I copy-paste your own answer. Please, accept it to close this question.

Comment: No problem, I will accept it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

It just need a pull-up resistor for the reset pin!